# Replace NaN values from one column with different length into other column with additional condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working with Titanic data set. This set have 891 rows. At moment I am focus on column 'Age'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
titanic_df = pd.read_csv('titanic_data.csv')
titanic_df ['Age']
```

Column 'Age' have 177 Nan values, so I want to replace this values from values from my sample. I already made sample for this column and you can see code below.

```
age_sample= titanic_df ['Age'][titanic_df ['Age'].notnull()].sample(177)
```

So next steep should be replacing Nan value from age_sample into titanic_df ['Age']. In order to do this I try with this lines of code.

```
titanic_df ['Age']=age_sample

titanic_df ['Age'].isna()=age_sample
```

But obliviously here I made some mistakes. So can anybody help me how to replace value from sample (177 rows) into original data set (891 rows) and replace only Nan values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A two line solution:

```py
age_sample = df['Age'][df['Age'].notnull()]
df['Age']  = list(age_sample) + list(age_sample.sample(177))
```

If number of `NaN` values is not known:

```py
nan_len = len(df['Age'][df['Age'].isna()])
age_sample = df['Age'][df['Age'].notnull()]
df['Age']  = list(age_sample) + list(age_sample.sample(nan_len ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the subframe you want to update using `loc`:

```
titanic_df.loc[titanic_df['Age'].isna(), 'Age'] = age_sample
```

Comment: I already execute this line in Python. There is no error, but problem is same or in other words Nan values are still there.

Answer (score 1):

I will divide my answer to two parts. Solution you are looking for and solution that makes it more robust.

#### Solution you are looking for

We have to find the number of missing values first, then generate number of sample matching our missing value and then assign. This will insure that you have the same size of needed missing values.

```py
...
age_na_size = titanic_df ['Age'].isna().sum()

# generate sample of that sum
age_sample= titanic_df ['Age'][titanic_df ['Age'].notnull()].sample(age_na_size)

# feed that to missing values
titanic_df.loc[titanic_df['Age'].isna(), 'Age'] = age_sample
```

#### Solutions to make it robust

1. find the group mean age and replace missing values according. Example group by gender, carbin etc features that makes sense and use median age as a replacer.
2. Use k-Nearest Neighbour as age replacer. See scikit-learn
   [knnimputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html#sklearn.impute.KNNImputer)
3. Use bins of age instead of actual ages. In this way you can first create a classifier to predict the age bin then use that as your code imputer.